# Facing issue with JPA merge. Merge operation not reflecting in DB and query is executing twice

Tags: java, jpa, merge

I am new to JPA and am facing this issue for the past two days . Whenever i am trying to update my object in the database , the merge query is executing twice and the data is not updated in the Database . Can any one tell me where i have done mistake .

here is the Snippet :

```
Employee emp = em.find(Employee.class,empid);
if (emp != null) {
    emp.setDescription("Success");
    emp.setDob(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

    etxn = em.getTransaction();
    etxn.begin();
    em.merge(emp);
    System.out.println(em.merge(emp));
    etxn.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are calling merge method twice

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same EntityManager, and JPA transactions, you do not even need to call merge.

Perhaps enable logging and include the log.  Also include the code for you class.